# login shell and interactive shell?

Tags: shell

Can anyone tell me what are login shell and interactive shell and which configurations each of them read(etc/profile, etc/bashrc, .bash_profile ...)??

I saw some explanation like this:
A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or
one started with the --login option.
An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and
without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected
to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i
option. PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing
a shell script or a startup file to test this state.

But this confused more !!!

Answer (score 0):

The `man bash` command on your system (`INVOCATION` section) talks about all of this and it describes which files are read when.

Comment: thanks for your hint, but when I invoke a bash (already log in), it's an interactive shell which should read .bashrc right? But my .bashrc was not unless i manually source it. I don't know why??

Comment: Yes, it should be read at that point.  Is it located directly in your home directory (`ls ~/.bashrc`)?  Are any `BASH_*` kinds of environment variables set?  How exactly is `bash` invoked, and from where (`which bash`)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't trust the manual page, try using strace.

```
strace -o/tmp/tr -f bash
exit
grep open /tmp/tr | grep $HOME
```

For me, this shows:

```
18316 open("/home/sethrobertson/.bashrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

What does it show for you?